# Inverse function of scipy.spatial.distance.squareform

Tags: python, scipy

Is there an inverse function of scipy.spatial.distance.squareform? If not, what is the best way to write it to handle huge distance matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs, `squareform` is its own inverse:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this lambda is quite efficient:

```
In [1]: unsquareform = lambda a: a[numpy.nonzero(numpy.triu(a))]
```

For example:

```
In [2]: scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(numpy.arange(12).reshape((4,3)))
Out[2]:
array([  5.19615242,  10.39230485,  15.58845727,   5.19615242,
        10.39230485,   5.19615242])
```

and

```
In [3]: unsquareform(scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(numpy.arange(12).reshape((4,3)))))
Out[3]:
array([  5.19615242,  10.39230485,  15.58845727,   5.19615242,
        10.39230485,   5.19615242])
```